# listening to a port from within wine?

Tags: wine

I'd like to communicate through OSC to some software running in Wine, but when I start the OSC server from within wine, I don't see any ports listening (on the linux host).
Is it possible to have wine use my network, or can wine listen on its own virtual network such that I can forward requests to it?

Comment: There's no virtual network in wine. Maybe the port <=1024 and you're not root?

Comment: I'll try this, but the port is 8000